# Setting Navigation Icon on Android ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, drawerlayout

So I'm working on adding ActionBarSherlock and the Navigation Drawer to a project that previously implemented a custom (very poorly written) "action bar". Instead of using fragments and a backstack of activities for navigation, some activities show and hide different layouts.  (That is, suppose I am in a list mode and then select a button to go into an edit screen.  The app currently hides the list layout and shows another layout.).

So I've added actionbar sherlock and a navigation drawer to all the activities.  I want to be able to programmatically switch the navigation icon from the 3 lines to the arrow when certain buttons are pressed.

[image]

I can't figure out how to do this though.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to use the method:

```
setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(boolean enable)
```

inside the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class.

Answer (score 6):

After:

```
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
```

Use this code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.select);
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends how wedded you are to built-in actionbar artifacts. You can always redraw the current actionbar by inflating a layout of your choosing, then calling

```
getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
// Inflate and do whatever you need to your view...
getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(abView);
getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().show();
```

When you want to go back to your standard (assuming you're using a DrawerLayout to do your navigation drawer), you can just set make a call to `setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false)` (re-enable showHome and showTitle as you please).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that would work, but unfortunately I think its not the most practical solution.  Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, customization of the back button can only be done via themes. Besides, swapping the drawer icon for the back icon (within the same Activity) doesn't make sense, since users would still be able to access the navigation drawer by sliding the left most edge to the right. It just wouldn't make sense.

If you absolutely need the back icon, then it would make the most sense to make that screen a new Activity since you would indeed be adding another "level" to the stack, which is what the back icon represents.

Comment: I agree it doesn't make sense, but I have to work with what I've been given... =/

I kind of want to imitate adding another level to the stack.  In the short run, I thought it would be easier to swap the images and override the android.R.id.home menu item press.  So I could get this version published.  But, perhaps you're right, maybe I just should make it into another activity.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree that it doesn't make sense, but in any case, my opinion is of little value. The truth is that Google does this in the Google Music app. When you tap on an album from the "home", you are taken to an activity whose action bar shows the "back" caret (and it takes you back) yet you STILL have a drawer if you drag. Here's a sshot of the above app, notice the action bar, notice how I am dragging from the left and the drawer is coming: https://www.dropbox.com/sc/qs00ozm18n6v3ep/a3JuhL9LPu