# How to remove Navigation drawer icon

Tags: android, navigation, actionbarsherlock

How to remove pointed icon in Navigation Drawer, I just playing with Navigation Drawer, I just wanted to maintain only one icon. [image]

Comment: You got your solution [Here][1] and for more info follow [This][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135214/hide-actionbar-menuitems-when-navigation-drawer-slides-for-any-amount
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707029/setting-navigation-icon-on-android-actionbar

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had same issue and I solved with adding this line in `onCreate()`:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

it will hide icon from navigation drawer.

Comment: You can add the following line in case of hiding also the navigation up:
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0):

Which implementation are you using for the Navigation Drawer?

Also, why do you want to remove it? You could keep the icon there and use an actual icon instead of one trying to show that it is a menu next to your "Home" text.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a bit too late for answer?

1 way to remove the 3 stripes from the app is

> replace the **ic_drawer.png** in every **drawable** folder with nothing (eg. with transparent icon)

You also can replace with any icon you want too.