# Customize Navigation Drawer Action Bar (App Compact) in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to customize navigation drawer app compact action bar, I want to remove app icon from that and want to make its title center in action bar.

I have applied all solutions , but nothing is working with all the conditions.

Please give me some clue for applying it correctly

Comment: You shouldn't do it! It is NOT an ANDROID pattern!

Comment: it is the requirement , can you please tell me the way

Comment: I already answered how to remove icon from navigation drawer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727233/how-to-remove-navigation-drawer-icon/22612901#22612901). And for Align actionbar title center in android [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387345/how-to-align-actionbar-title-center-in-android).

Comment: there is a miraculous methods like button.openDrawer(drawer) and button.closeDrawer(drawer) :))

Comment: I want to just remove app icon from action bar, not toggle icon; and I tried both links, but applying custom layout not working for all conditions like when drawer open.

Comment: removing app icon maybe not an ideal way to do what you want. the best way is to create a custom action bar. I already did customizing action bar. I just add a button to open the drawer. Just i said set on button.onClickListener the drawerLayout.openDrawer() and drawerLayout.closeDrawer()

Comment: can you please guide me how to apply above succession, I need some hint, how to apply our own toggle button in our custom layout, and fetch its id for apply onClickListener.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. As mentioned, I have two problems, and I solved that in following way :

1) For making title centre, we need to make custom layout of action bar, and need to remove action bar title.

2) for remove app icon from action bar, we need to set `android:icon` property of that activity in manifest with transparent image or colour.

Answer (score 1):

You should creat a customize action bar. Then, if you want you can add a button that can open and close your drawerlayout.

Comment: @mark you can address your button as like this. DrawerButton = (ImageView) actionBarLayout
    .findViewById(R.id.bSideButton);

DrawerButton is my Button on my action bar. and actionBarLayout is my ViewGroup