# ActionBarDrawerToggle not accepting R.drawable file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I am really new to Android Studio. I can't figure out how to make ActionBarDrawerToggle take the navigation drawer image that I am trying to pass it. It gives me the error that it was expecting a Toolbar instead of an Int (my image). Please see a picture (Toolbar error link) of the error I am getting below.

I understand from: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html that the ActionBarDrawerToggle should be able to take my drawable resource file which I downloaded from the above link. I have no idea how to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is my error image: [Toolbar error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKyNV.png)

EDIT: so i got help from this link: [ActionBarDrawerToggle No Suitable Constructor Drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581764/actionbardrawertoggle-no-suitable-constructor-drawable?rq=1)
The answer said to remove the drawable file since this is android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
So I did but other people are complaining that this makes an up action and doesn't show the drawer icon. So I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22612901/5482380
But not sure if this is good solution???????????

Comment: It appears that the class they reference in this example from the `v4` support library is now [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html). Unfortunately, the [recommended `v7` version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) doesn't use a constructor that accepts a drawable resource id.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Please see me edits. I haven't tested what happens yet since I am working on an integrated project. I am building my own project to test what happens when I do this. But other people are complaining about some up action that appears when using v7.

Answer (score 0):

The example referenced in that tutorial is from the now [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) `v4` support library. The [recommended](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) version is now in the `v7` library. The constructor for the `v7` version however does not take the `id` of a `drawable`, but instead a `Toolbar` (as shown in your error message).

I would suggest you try the `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled()` and `setHomeAsUpIndicator()` methods. The latter takes either a `drawable` or an `id` as its argument ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(boolean))).

**Edit:** There is also the [`setNavigationIcon()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#setNavigationIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) method on your `Toolbar`

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast response! I am new to android studio so I don't understand all the things I need to fix/add to this now. I am looking for a good tutorial on this if you know of any? Thank you so much!

Comment: I found this tutorial: http://devsonline.in/content/index/category/android/topic/navigation_drawer_-_fragment_indroduction

Comment: @aahmed31 I don't have any tutorial recommendations unfortunately! Are you using `Toolbar` in your app? I'd recommend you try that ( [this](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html) tutorial looks like it covers it, though we're on v23 of the support library now) and then use the `setNavigationIcon()` method above on your `Toolbar`.